# optional chaining in javascript causing error in eslint

Tags: javascript, arrays, eslint, eslintrc, optional-chaining

i tried to use optional chaining in javascript but my eslint rules causing error .

**Error : Unsafe usage of optional chaining. If it short-circuits with 'undefined' the evaluation will throw TypeError  no-unsafe-optional-chaining**

```
const { homeAddress, officeAddress} = Employee?.addresses;
```

**Error : Unsafe arithmetic operation on optional chaining. It can result in NaN
no-unsafe-optional-chaining**

```
const AddressesCount = homeAddress?.length + officeAddress?.length
```

how can I fix this issue ? I do not want to violate the rule

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fix this, or you can use `/* eslint-disable-next-line no-unsafe-optional-chaining */`. Which I would not advise but it will fix the errors.
The best way to fix this in my opinion is by using `const { homeAddress, officeAddress } = Employee?.addressess || {};`. What you can also try is `const { addresses: { homeAddress, officeAddress } } = Employee;`

Comment: `Employee.addresses || {}` will throw an exception if `Employee` is null or undefined ...

Comment: so how can i overcome that issue ? @derpirscher

Comment: Like you did in your original code: `Employee?.addresses` but you need the fallback to an empty object, so that the deconstruction won't throw an error on null or undefined. So `Employee?.addresses || {}`

Comment: You are absolutely right i will edit my nswer

Answer (score 3):

for the second issue:

```js
const AddressesCount = (homeAddress?.length || 0) + (officeAddress?.length || 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide a default value

```
const { addresses: { homeAddress, officeAddress} = { homeAddress: '', officeAddress: ''} } = Employee

console.log(homeAddress) // <empty string>
console.log(officeAddress) // <empty string>
```

This way you're making sure keys exists and you'll be getting a default value(empty string in this case) and your code doesn't breaks.